# How to chain SQL select results in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having difficulties selecting multiple results with child/parent relationships. Here are the tables with a tree of categories. The `category` table represents relationships, while `category_name` table contains name strings:

```
[category]                 [category_name]
id, id_parent              id, name
-------------              --------------
1   NULL                   1   'animal'
2   1                      2   'mammal'
3   2                      3   'lion'
4   2                      4   'sea_creature'
5   4                      5   'lion'
```

As an input I have names, which must be translated into id's. The hierarchy is exactly 3 levels deep. For example: `animal, mammal, lion,` -> `1, 2, 3`.

As you can see `lion` name used for different categories. However, upper level category is unique and names of sub-categories are unique within one parent category.

I could make three separate queries, starting from `animal` and then reusing its `id` to compare with `id_parent` of subsequent queries:

Query #1:

```
SELECT
    cn.id
FROM
    category_name cn
WHERE
    cn.name = 'animal'
```

(Save result of this query in a variable `parent`)

Query #2:

```
SELECT
    cn.id
FROM
    category_name cn
INNER JOIN category c ON cn.id = c.id
WHERE
    cn.name = 'mammal' AND c.id_parent = <parent>
```

And so on. But I'm sure there is better way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use "UNION" and be sure about performance while using this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT c1.id, c2.id, c3.id
FROM category c1
JOIN category c2 ON c1.id = c2.id_parent
JOIN category c3 ON c2.id = c3.id_parent
JOIN category_name cn1 ON c1.id = cn1.id
JOIN category_name cn2 ON c2.id = cn2.id
JOIN category_name cn3 ON c3.id = cn3.id
WHERE cn1.name = 'animal' AND cn2.name = 'mammal' AND cn3.name = 'lion'
```

Output

```
| C1ID | C2ID | C3ID |
|------|------|------|
|    1 |    2 |    3 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd652/1).

As a side note, I'd recommend you to Google for "nested sets" as well as "adjacency lists".